# click on iframe and be redirected to another webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, click

I see a lot of posts on how to make an iframe clickable, but I cant seem to get any of them to work.

Does anybody know a way the user can click an iframe and be redirected to another webpage?

I'm writing this as html in notepad (yep primitive but I don't usually write html code)

Comment: Could you link to some of these posts you're trying to emulate? Or just explain better what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a link within a frame you may have to use the [`target` attribute on the `anchor` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target).

E.g. `<a href="www.somewhere.com" target="_parent">This will take the parent window</a>`

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/n84yp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can put transparent png image exactly as large as the iframe in the iframe and put it in

```
 <a href="yourlink"><img id="transparent" src="transparent.png"></a>
```

and bring it to front with

```
 #transparent { 
 z-index:100;
 }
```

in CSS
and if you dont want to make that transparent image your self just download transparent png in any size and in css adjust its height and width as you want